# Equivalence of quadratic forms over arbitrary field (char(K)≠2)

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be an arbitrary field with $char(\mathbb{K})\neq 2$ and let $a_1, \ldots ,a_n$ be Elements of $\mathbb{K}$.

I want to proof the following equivalence of $n-$quadratic forms in diagonal form over $\mathbb{K}$:
$ \begin{align}
[a_1, \ldots ,a_n] \simeq [c_1^2a_1, \ldots , c_n^2a_n],
\end{align}
$ 
where $c_1, \ldots , c_n \in \mathbb{K}^* \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

According to Lam's Book $\textit{Introduction to quadratic forms}$ (p. 1-2) it suffices to find an
"$\textit{invertible matrix}$ $C \in GL_n(\mathbb{K})$ $\textit{such that}$ $ g(C\cdot X)=f(X)$. (1) $\textit{This means there exists a nonsingular, homogenuous linear substitution of the variables}$ $X_1, \ldots ,X_n $ $ \textit{that takes the form}$ $g$ $\textit{to the form}$ $f$."

Now I was going to define the isometry

$C:=diag(\sqrt{c_1},\ldots ,\sqrt{c_n})$.

Clearly $C \in GL_n(\mathbb{K})$ and (1) would be established. But I cannot really say if this substitution is "homogenuous" as understood in Lem's sense.

Can someone give me insight into this?

Comment: I think homogeneous linear means $x \mapsto Cx$ not $x \mapsto Cx+b$. Anyway a quadratic form on $K^n$ is a function of the form $q_A(x) = x^\top A x, x \in K^n$ for some matrix $A = A^\top \in M_n(K)$ and $q_A \simeq q_B$ over $K$ iff  $q_A(x) =q_B(Cx)$ for some $C \in GL_n(K)$ ie. $A = C^\top B C$ and $B = C^{-\top} A C^{-1}$ and $q_B(x) = q_A(C^{-1}x)$

Comment: @reuns So I'm done, plain and simple?